# Outlook Addin - Get current selected calendar date

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

When right clicking on a calendar and running a ribbon action is it possible to get the selected calendar date the same way you would get the current mailItem or appointmentItem?

Ribbon XML:

```
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuCalendarView">
    <menu id="CallenderMenu" label="Actions">
        <button id="NewDiaryEvent" label="Create new" onAction="CreateCallenderItem_click" />
    </menu>
</contextMenu>
```

C#:

```
public void CreateCallenderItem_click(IRibbonControl control)
{
    // Get selected calendar date
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dmitry is correct but here is an example of the code I have used to get the start and finish date of the area you have selected:

```
public void CreateCallenderItem_click(IRibbonControl control)
{
    // Get selected calendar date
    Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.Explorer explorer = application.ActiveExplorer();
    Outlook.Folder folder = explorer.CurrentFolder as Outlook.Folder;
    Outlook.View view = explorer.CurrentView as Outlook.View;

    if (view.ViewType == Outlook.OlViewType.olCalendarView)
    {
        Outlook.CalendarView calView = view as Outlook.CalendarView;
        DateTime calDateStart = calView.SelectedStartTime;
        DateTime calDateEnd = calView.SelectedEndTime;

        // Do stuff with dates. 
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you some more.

Answer (score 2):

Read Application.ActiveExplorer.CuurentFolder.CurrentView property, check if it is CalendarView, then read the CalendarView.SelectedStartTime property.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation on this for C#. I can only find documentation on VB.

Comment: Ive found some documentation but when I do Application.ActiveExplorer it is unknown.