# Outlook Addin - Get current selected calendar date in C++

Tags: c++, com, outlook-addin

I would like to programmatically get the selected calendar date in a C++ outlook plugin I'm patching.
This presumably involves using the SelectedStartTime and SelectedEndTime properties of the CalendarView object.

I've scoured SO (and the web) and found the solution in VB and C#, but I have trouble migrating the implementation to C++. I was able to get the view object - but I dont know how to get the calendarView object.

This is the original SO question in C#:
[Outlook Addin - Get current selected calendar date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040715/outlook-addin-get-current-selected-calendar-date)

This is the implementation I have (so far) in C++. Note that it is incomplete:

```
CComPtr<Outlook::_Explorer> spExplorer;
Outlook::MAPIFolder * pFolder;
CComPtr<Outlook::View> view;



hr = m_pHostApp->ActiveExplorer(&spExplorer);   
if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && spExplorer)
{
    hr =  spExplorer->get_CurrentFolder(&pFolder);
    if ((SUCCEEDED(hr)) && pFolder)
    {
        hr = pFolder->get_CurrentView(&view);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            Outlook::OlViewType viewType;
            hr = view->get_ViewType(&viewType);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                if (viewType == Outlook::olCalendarView)
                {
                      //the vb/C# solutions suggest that I need a calendar 
                      //view object here and somehow get its           
                      //SelectedStartTime and SelectedEndTime. 
                      //However I suspect there's no such object.. so I must be doing
                      //something wrong.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call QueryInterface on the view variable to query for the CalendarView interface, then use CalendarView::SelectedStartTime / SelectedEndTime properties.

Comment: Ha! that makes sense - I was looking for a way to "cast" the object - and what's more natural than using COM's casting mechanism. Thank you Sir. I'll try this tomorrow and return to accept your answer.

Comment: So. I'm going to accept your answer - it is correct. I'm still having troubles implementing this. Specifically, the interface doesn't exist in my code. Do I need to declare the _CalendarView interface and its properties in my .idl file? I just don't know enough COM :/

Comment: Did you import the Outlook type library using #import?

Comment: Thanks again for helping. I'm just maintaining this piece of software so I dont have all the answers. But it does appear that we're importing a "OUTL.OLB" - I guess that's it. However, its from 2004 - perhaps I need to get a newer version and try with that.

Comment: Okay. I've confirmed that newer versions of the OLB file include the missing CalendarView type - so I should be fine now. Thanks again!